# Enable and disable mouse scroll by clicking on an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll, event-handling

I would to trigger a `scroll event` by clicking on a little link in my html page.
With JS I can block scroll on window but when I return to `data-click-state 1` I cannot scroll anymore

Here is the code:

```
$('#lista-food').on('click',function(){

  if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
    $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)

    $("#lista_ul-food").addClass( "top_enter-food" );
    $("ul#lista_ul-food").addClass("active");
    $("body").addClass("overflow-hidden");
    $(".top-lista").addClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-lista").addClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-lista").addClass("bottom-animate");

    $(document).unbind("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll");
    $(window).unbind("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll");

  } else {
    $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)

    $("#lista_ul-food").removeClass( "top_enter-food" );
    $("ul#lista_ul-food").removeClass("active");
    $("body").removeClass("overflow-hidden");
    $(".top-lista").removeClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-lista").removeClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-lista").removeClass("bottom-animate");

    $(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll" );
    $(document).on("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll");
  }     
});
```

My JS connect with this Js called Velocity.js [Download JS Velocity](http://www.filedropper.com/main_8)

Comment: can you give a fiddle?

Comment: Cannot simply invoke `event.preventDefault()` in an event Handler?

Comment: @morels you can try to explain me your question, please :)

Comment: in my answer i provided a fiddle, a code playground containing a portion of code. in this case your code, functioning. pls see below.

Comment: hi man! i upload another js! maybe this is our problem! check it please and thanks for your feedback

Comment: you cannot use such environments to share code. please use a code playground and/or post here your code. this question is about to be flagged as 'bug not reproducible' or 'external download resource'

Comment: @morels problem solved! thanks! your last js it's cool! thanks and greetings from italy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#lista-food').on('click',function(){
  function myfunc(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  if($(this).attr('data-click-state') === "1") {
    $(this).attr('data-click-state', "0");

    $(document).on("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", myfunc);
    $(window).on("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", myfunc);

  } else {
    $(this).attr('data-click-state', "1")

    $(document).unbind("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll");
    $(window).unbind("keydown mousewheel DOMMouseScroll");
  }

  $("#lista_ul-food").toggleClass( "top_enter-food" );
  $("ul#lista_ul-food").toggleClass("active");
  $("body").toggleClass("overflow-hidden");
  $(".top-lista").toggleClass("top-animate");
  $(".mid-lista").toggleClass("mid-animate");
  $(".bottom-lista").toggleClass("bottom-animate");  
});
```

**update:**

Pls see this functioning [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ry8kLha/).

Comment: if i change my js with yours, my website cant block scroll :(